# Replacing a string with quotes selectively using sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have a file.

```
$ cat file
"bar":  false
"foo":  false
```

I need to replace the word `false` with `true` only in the pattern `"foo":  false`. The problem is quotes and spaces.

I thought about two ways:

1. To isolate the whole pattern in some sort of qoutes/double quotes.
2. To replace only such "false" which has a "foo" before it.

An example try of 2 option:

```
$ sed -i 's/\(.*foo\)/false/true\1/g' file
```

It failed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an address. The quotes are not a problem if you single quote your `sed` expression

```
$ sed '/"foo"/ s/false/true/' file
"bar":  false
"foo":  true
```

If you really need to match the whole pattern, fine:

```
$ sed '/"foo": *false/ s/false/true/' file
"bar":  false
"foo":  true
```

`*` matches any number of the preceding character (space).

You can use `\s` to also match tabs (any horizontal whitespace):

```
sed '/"foo":\s*false/ s/false/true/' file
```

Add the `-i` option after testing to modify the original file.

Comment: Most welcome, thanks for asking :) @JosefKlimuk